# C Function pointer - not assigned but still works. Is there default behavior?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have this code from a program given to me from a highly qualified instructor. Note the function pointer cmpfn below. It is used as a comparison operator. I did some reading up on function pointers and they make sense. However, nowhere in this codebase do I see it assigned to an actual defined function as I see in the tutorials I read online. It is never defined and assigned anywhere yet it appears to work. Is there some default behavior or how would you get this to work without assigning it as in `cmpfn = &function_defined_elsewhere;` ? Also why might he chose to use this function pointer as opposed to just a straight comparison operator?

```
/**
 * Find an element in the list
 *
 * cmpfn should return 0 if the comparison to this node's data is equal.
 */
void *llist_find(struct llist *llist, void *data, int (*cmpfn)(void *, void *))
{
    struct llist_node *n = llist->head;

    if (n == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (n != NULL) {
        if (cmpfn(data, n->data) == 0) {
            break;
        }

        n = n->next;
    }

    if (n == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return n->data;
}
```

Edit (Responding to feedback): Solved! What's below is for general public edification/curiosity but it makes sense to me now. Thanks for your indulgences.

I see now I needed to find where this function was being called. The above was in a file called llist.h and the pointer to the function (p2f) is called in a file called hashtable.c - twice actually. He actually uses p2f's a lot.

Here is one instance of a "p2f hosting" function being called:

```
/**
 * Get from the hash table with a binary data key
 */
void *hashtable_get_bin(struct hashtable *ht, void *key, int key_size)
{
    int index = ht->hashf(key, key_size, ht->size);

    struct llist *llist = ht->bucket[index];

    struct htent cmpent;
    cmpent.key = key;
    cmpent.key_size = key_size;

    struct htent *n = llist_find(llist, &cmpent, htcmp); // HERE

    if (n == NULL) { return NULL; }

    return n->data;
}
```

So it's being passed htcmp. Previously I thought you had to assign a p2f to a function with the "=", but you can also do it through passing into calling function. I only learned about these today!

Here is htcmp's def:

```
/**
 * Comparison function for hashtable entries
 */
int htcmp(void *a, void *b)
{
    struct htent *entA = a, *entB = b;

    int size_diff = entB->key_size - entA->key_size;

    if (size_diff) {
        return size_diff;
    }

    return memcmp(entA->key, entB->key, entA->key_size);
}
```

So it clearly returns an int, depending on difference between two htent (hashtable entry), noting either size difference or else calling powerful memcmp function.

This was a challenge to get to. The basics make sense but his code is very busy. I'll have to consolidate it in my sleep. There are so many structs and pointers to functions and much else interacting, but it was and is a great learning experience.

Comment: The caller of the function sets the pointer. You need to show/look at the calling code.

Comment: *why might he chose to use this function pointer as opposed to just a straight comparison operator*. The reason is to make this find function generic without needing to know the type of `data` or how to compare the `data`.

Comment: *why might he chose to use this function pointer as opposed to just a straight comparison operator?* Also, a `void *` doesn't have a type and it can't be dereferenced, so  you can't compare what the two pointers point to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the function llist_find you should pass the reference to the function, which must have the same prototype that is expected for llist_find.

And to answer your question, it's very helpful to use a pointer to function, especially when you are working with a structure where the comparison (this case) can be performed over one or multiple members of the structure. Also, as the function use void pointers, you can use the same llist_find to handle lists of different kind of structures.

Answer (score 0):

You set the Pointer in This Parameter. So, when you call this Function I will automatically set these pointers automatically. So, I think you should look around the calling of this fuction. Then you will get the solution of your question

```
void *llist_find(struct llist *llist, void *data, int (*cmpfn)(void *, void *))
```